# Infinite loop with integer text file reading in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

Hi I have a fairly simple program but I am having trouble understanding why I have an inifite loop when I am running it. The file I am reading from has 10 integers in it. I am using Eclipse Juno and the output in the console is counting by 1 starting at 281363 infinitely. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestScoreAnalyzer
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
        int arraySize = 0;

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Quinn\\workspace\\CPS121\\src\\
                             additionalAssignments\\scoresSample.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while(inputFile.hasNextInt())
    {
    arraySize++;
    System.out.println(arraySize);
    }

    inputFile.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're never calling `inputFile.nextInt()` - you're *only* calling `hasNextInt()`, which doesn't actually advance the location in the file. You probably want:

```
while (inputFile.hasNextInt())
{
    arraySize++;
    System.out.println(arraySize);
    int value = inputFile.nextInt();
    // Do something with the value?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()

Scanner isnt moving on - its just saying the next one is an int (looks at the same one each time)